# Check required inputs with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, input

I have 4 inputs on my page, and on a button onClick, i want to check, that all the inputs are filled with text.

```
<input type="text" value="" id="input1">
<input type="text" value="" id="input2">
<input type="text" value="" id="input3">
<input type="text" value="" id="input4">
```

What i want : Store all the required inputs ID in an array, and on click, check, that is there any input, that is empty.

How can i do this at the simplest way?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: simplest way is to try something yourself check on `.each()` , `:empty`, or check `.length`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validating multiple fields in a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10856887/validating-multiple-fields-in-a-form)

Comment: See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#required

Answer (score 4):

Use required tag instead as given below

```
<input type="text" value="" id="input1" required>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also try adding **REGEX** for more strict checking

```
 // using Plain JavaScript

  var input1= document.getElementById('input1').value;
  if(input1 == "" ){
      alert("Input 1 is Empty");
        return false;
  }

  var input2 = document.getElementById('input2').value;
  if(input12 == "" ){
      alert("Input 2 is Empty");
        return false;
  }

  var input3 = document.getElementById('input3').value;
  if(input3 == "" ){
      alert("Input 3 is Empty");
        return false;
  }


  var input4 = document.getElementById('input4').value;
  if(input4 == "" ){
      alert("Input 4 is Empty");
        return false;
  }
```

Comment: But how can i do this with multiple inputs?

Comment: same code chunk for each of the input, let me update code for you.

Answer (score 0):

just incase the required attribute fails.. you can do this.. 
add a validate function to the blur event, that is when the user leaves the field..

```
<input type="text" onblur="validate(this)" value="" id="input1">
<input type="text" onblur="validate(this)" value="" id="input2">
<input type="text" onblur="validate(this)" value="" id="input3">
<input type="text" onblur="validate(this)" value="" id="input4">

<button> ... </button>
```

and using jquery you can do this..

```
 function validate(obj){
    if($(obj).val() == ''){
       alert('this Field cannot be empty');
       $(obj).focus();  //send focus back to the object...
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" value="" id="input1">
<input type="text" value="" id="input2">
<input type="text" value="" id="input3">
<input type="text" value="" id="input4">






jQuery(function($){

                var arr = [];
                // number of input elements
                var count = $("input").length;
                // store list of input ids
                $("buttonName").on('click', function(event) {
                     $("input").each(function(i){
                        var currId = $(this).attr('id');
                        arr.push(currId);
                        if ($(this).val()=="") {
                            alert(currId+": has no input");
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
```